# ANGULAR2 How to populate forms with data from database primise?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-promise, angular2-formbuilder

I'm new in angular and firebase too, so i'm suffering to populate my forms with   from firebase promise data. Yes, I´m suffering too to understand how to deal with promises vs observables.
I will apreciate any help.

```
ngOnInit() {

this.form = this.fb.group({
        'email': ['', [ Validators.required,
                      Validators.pattern('^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$')]],
        'name': ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
        'country':  ['', [ Validators.minLength(8)]],
        'state':  ['', [ Validators.minLength(8)]],
        'city':  ['', [ Validators.minLength(8)]],
        'sexualOpt':  ['', [ Validators.minLength(8)]],
        'marital':  ['', [ Validators.minLength(8)]],
        'dateOfBirth':  ['', [ Validators.minLength(8)]],
        'noChildren':  ['', [ Validators.minLength(8)]],
        'schoolar':  ['', [ Validators.minLength(8)]]
});
this.readProfile() ;}



readProfile() {
firebase.database().ref( 'User/'  + 'xs9XP4Aq2aVt0q5CkCuocrYyHwC3' + '/profile'  )
         .once('value')
         .then (function(snapshot) {
          this.form.controls['name'].setValue(snapshot.val().name);
          console.log(snapshot.val());
         });
;}
```

Console shows:
Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"

Regards

Comment: are you using AngularFire service?

Comment: Not in this part, I tested angularfire2 before. 
My IMPORTS:
<code>
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
<code>

Comment: I note that in "app.module.ts" I still using 
 AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, authConfig).
 I have to change  AngularFireModule ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create form with initial values:

```
fields.forEach(field => {
  this.form.addControl(field.name,
    new FormControl({
      value: formValues[field.name],
      disabled: field.read_only || this.isFormDisabled()
    }, this.getValidators(field.type)));
});
```

or set it like you do:

```
this.survey.controls['account'].patchValue(survey.account);
this.survey.controls['account'].setValue(survey.account);
```

**log your data** as `console.log('snapshot', snapshot)` and see what you receive than use data properly.